# Layout won't hide after being shown

Tags: android

I am writing an app for Android that requires a drop down layout. By this I mean I want an entire new layout appear and disappear at the click of one button. I did some research, and the only somewhat viable option would seem to be spinners. However, spinners aren't large enough for what I want to include in the drop down menu(for context, there will be multiple sliders, buttons and text fields in this dropdown, so it needs to be full sized.)

So I am trying to use the VISIBILITY tag in XML and the setVisible function in Java to get this to work. When the user clicks the button, the layout does appear, however when I want to hide the menu by clicking the button again, the layout is still visible, when I want it to be 'gone'.

Now onto the code.
First, the main XML file where all of this is shown:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#bbcde3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="#3fa9f5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:text="@string/settings_button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</GridLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/rys"
    android:textColor="#888888"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    style="@style/circleRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.0"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dropDownButton"
    android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:onClick="dropDown"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:src="@drawable/ddb" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dropDownLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/testTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Testing dropdown"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/tipTitle"
    android:textColor="#888888"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the main java file:

```
package com.example.tipquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener {

// Testing Stuff to show the rating value, will need to use later for maths
RatingBar rb;
TextView tv;
// The Image used as the DropDown button, Rotate code below
ImageView dropDownButton;

RelativeLayout dropDownLayout;
Boolean hasRotated = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dropDownLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dropDownLayout);
    dropDownButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dropDownButton);
    // tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
    // ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1))
    // .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
//Visibilities: 0 = Visible, 1 = Invisible, 2 = Gone
public void dropDown(View view){
    if(hasRotated == false){
        dropDownButton.setRotation(90);
        dropDownLayout.setVisibility(0);
        hasRotated = true;
    }else if(hasRotated == true){
        dropDownButton.setRotation(0);
        dropDownLayout.setVisibility(2);
        hasRotated = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromTouch) {
    // final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
    tv.setText(rating + "/5.0");
}
// http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-rating-bar-example.html#.U7SZ5fldXm4
// http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.ca/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-ratingbar-in.html
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure its a very stupid mistake on my part, but I'm stymied. If there is a better way to go about what I want to do, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Fragment , you just will need layout defined in your xml with ID , and you use Fragment transaction

```
    transactionPopUp = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Fragment that hold your items 
    addItemViewFragment = new AddItemViewFragment();
    transactionPopUp.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom,
                R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);
    // R.id.pop_up_layout Layout in your xml
    transactionPopUp.add(R.id.pop_up_layout, addItemViewFragment);
    transactionPopUp.commit();
```

Comment: Where exactly would I post this in the code? Would this go into the dropDown method?I assume the transactionPopUp variable you show is a FragmentTransaction, am I correct? I've looked at a bunch of docs and examples, and so I have a java class that extends fragment, and I have the XML entry all ready to go. Just need to know what to do with this code for the desired output.

Comment: you use that code to attach your Fragment to your layout in xml , so use it when you want to show up the dialog

Comment: So it does go into the method I though. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sorry this is a bit late, but I've modified your code so it fits in the app. All works perfectly, until I try to hit the button again to hide the Fragment. I've tried using FragmentTransaction.hide(myFragment) and FragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment) neither hides the fragment. Both of these functions were in the else if(hasRotated == true) part of my if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is but i think you have to use

```
.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

or

```
View.INVISIBLE
```

or

```
View.GONE
```

[android references](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: I was looking at Android's documentation when I first looked into Visibility, and they said thusly:visible 0  Visible on screen; the default value.
invisible 1  Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
gone 2  Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

Answer (score 0):

You used:

```
//Visibilities: 0 = Visible, 1 = Invisible, 2 = Gone
...
dropDownLayout.setVisibility(2);
```

Integer values for visibility are:

Visible = 0
Invisible = 4
Gone = 8.

So you should use to hide view:

```
dropDownLayout.setVisibility(8);
```

or even better because it is more readable for others:

```
dropDownLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Using the View.GONE does work, thanks. However, I don't believe you're right about the 0, 4 and 8. Androids Official Docs say its 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29 and then tell me what Android Official Docs say... Click on Visible and you'll see "Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)", click on Invisible and you'll see "Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)", click on Gone and you'll see "Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)".

Comment: android:visibility

Controls the initial visibility of the view.

Must be one of the following constant values.

Constant Value Description
visible 0  Visible on screen; the default value.
invisible 1  Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
gone 2  Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.
This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol visibility.

Related Methods
setVisibility(int)

Comment: Did you try code with using 2 or 1? Because i did. 2 doesn't work and 8 does work. Try it in one of your applications and use view.setVisibility(2) and view.setVisibility(8); And tell me what works at your example!